# Rounding a pyodbc variables

Tags: python, html, django, rounding, pyodbc

I currently have the following code which gives the below-mentioned outputs

Code:
Views.py

```
creditTotal = ' Select SUM(Credit) FROM [Kyle].[dbo].[PostGL] WHERE Credit <> 0.0'
    cursor = cnxn.cursor();
    cursor.execute(creditTotal);
    xCreditTotal = cursor.fetchone()

    return render(request , 'main/Kyletrb.html' , {"xAlls":xAll_l , 'xCreditTotal':xCreditTotal})
```

Html.html:

```
{% for xCreditTotal in xCreditTotal %}
  <td><b>{{ xCreditTotal }}</b></td>
  {% endfor %}
```

Output:

> Total         485940.85000000003

How would I be able to round this value to 2 decimal places (e.g. 485940.00)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django uses the Jinja template, so you can use its round filer. It works as follows:

template.html

```
{% for xCreditTotal in xCreditTotal %}
  <td><b>{{ xCreditTotal| round(2, 'floor') }}</b></td>
{% endfor %}
```

Check out [Jinja's document on topic](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.round)

The SQL round function can also do this job:

```
creditTotal = ' Select ROUND(SUM(Credit) , 2) FROM [Kyle].[dbo].[PostGL] WHERE Credit <> 0.0'
```